# Eval within if statement

Tags: perl

How can I dynamically pass eq or ne inside perl if statement? I tried below but is not working:

```
my $this="this";
my $that="that";
my $cond='ne';
if($this eval($cond) $that)
{
  print "$cond\n";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need `eval` for this. Just use a [dispatch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table):

```
sub test {
    my %op = (
        eq => sub { $_[0] eq $_[1] },
        ne => sub { $_[0] ne $_[1] },
    );
    return $op{ $_[2] }->($_[0], $_[1]);        
}

if (test($this, $that, $cond)){
    print "$cond\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but is it possible to use eval here? I need to do a composite lookup with the hash.

Comment: Nice, but this solution would generate a set of _different_ anonymous subs (or closures, to be precise) on every call to test().

Comment: I think a better way is to pass `$v1` and `$v2` as args to the anon subs. E.g. `my %op = ( eq => sub { $_[0] eq $_[1] } ... ); return $op{$op}->( $v1, $v2 );`

Comment: @Dallaylaen: that's mostly optimized away, and entirely so in cases like this where there are no closed-over variables.

Comment: @ysth: Still a hash of unchanging subs is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Dallaylaen: that's what this answer does, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @ysth: Oh, I see. When I wrote my initial comment here, the post suggested binding $_[1,2] within sub{}'s and calling those as $op{...}->(), which seemed a bit too generous to me. That's what my remark was about. Now that the post was edited I see no problem at all. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (($cond eq 'eq') xor ($this ne $that)) {
     print $cond;
};
```

But maybe a better and more general approach would be to use perl's functional capabilities and create a hash table of functions:

```
my %compare = (
     eq => sub {shift eq shift},
     ne => sub {shift ne shift},
     lt => sub {shift lt shift},
     like => sub {$_[0] =~ /$_[1]/},
     # ....
);

#...
if ($compare{$cond}->($this, $that)) {
     print $cond;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are using `eval` for runtime code generation, it is best to keep in mind a few details.  First, `eval` is dangerous, so you should `eval` the smallest, most generic code you can, and check for errors.  Second, `eval` is slow, so you should store the result for later.

```
{my %cache;
sub compare {
    my ($x, $op, $y) = @_;
    $cache{$op} ||= eval "sub {\$_[0] $op \$_[1]}" || die "bad op: $op\n";
    $cache{$op}->($x, $y)
}}

my $this="this";
my $that="that";
my $cond='ne';

if (compare $this, $cond, $that) {
    print "$cond\n";
}
```

Here the `compare` function will build a new coderef (with `eval`) when it sees an operator that it has not had yet.  The return value of the `eval` is checked, and an error is raised if anything when wrong.

This coderef (which expects its values as arguments) is stored in `%cache`.  Then the cached coderef is run with the two values as arguments.  This same coderef will be used over and over whenever the same operator is used.